# Read Custom file from /app/ folder - Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-file

How can we read a file content which is located in the project /app/ folder?. My intention is to keep some credentials in that file and read the file in `build.gradle` or in `my application class`.

**I looking for an implementation like Firebase "google-services.json" file.**

Answer (score 1):

> How can we read a file content which is located in the project /app/ folder?

Those are files on your development machine. They are not necessarily files on the device.

> I looking for an implementation like Firebase "google-services.json" file.

AFAIK, that is used by a Gradle plugin on your development machine.

> My intention is to keep some credentials in that file and read the file in build.gradle or in my application class.

Store the data in `gradle.properties`. Those values can be accessed like global variables in your `build.gradle` file. In addition to using those values directly, you can use `buildConfigField` or `resValue` statements in `build.gradle` to make the values available to your app code (via `BuildConfig` or values-type resources, respectively).

If you would prefer not to use `gradle.properties`, you can create your own properties file, JSON file, XML file, etc. Your Gradle code would need to read in that file and extract values from it. Then, you can use `buildConfigField` or `resValue` to expose that data to your app code.

More elaborate possibilities include:

- Storing your data as an XML resource (`res/xml/`) for use at runtime, and teach your Gradle script to parse that file
- Storing your data as an asset (`assets/`) for use at runtime, and teach your Gradle script to parse that file

Comment: Thanks!. If I stored any where under "main" folder it can be identified by reverse engineering.

Comment: @MuhamedRiyasM: Everything in your APK can be identified by reverse engineering.

Comment: Oops!. But I cannot find the google-services.json file contents or even the file itself by reverse engineering!

Comment: @MuhamedRiyasM: As I wrote, AFAIK, that is processed by a Gradle plugin, and it is not directly at runtime.